# VS2015 NuGet inserts project instead of package

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I'm experience at strange behavior (or maybe I just don't get it) with VS2015 and Nuget.

I have two projects, an app and a library in two folders on the same level. The library project is build to a nuget package and pushed to a VSTS Packagemanager , and made accessable via Nuget by adding a new package source.

Now in my App project I try to install this Nuget package using packagemanager. I can pick the package and it's downloaded and everything, but for some reason, VS2015 now include the library project in the solution and reference the library from this project rather than from NuGet.

If the library project is moved away, so that VS2015 can't find it, then it uses the library from NuGet....

Why could VS2015 pick the project in favor of the NuGet package downloaded??
Is this expected behavior??
Should Library projects and App projects be placed it two completely different directory structures??

At least I'm a bit puzzled.....

Followup:

First of all the two projects are .NET core projects, don't know it that matters.

Both projects are pushed to VSTS Git. The library is build on VSTS and pushed to VSTS Packagemanager. I've added a Git source to VS2015, and installed the package as I'd do with any NuGet Package.

Comment: Do you build this ClassLibrary project as nuget package on local machine or using VSTS Build? I create a sample solution with one cliassLibrary and a app. Then I pack the ClassLibrary as a NuGet Package on local machine and push it to VSTS Packagemanager. No matter I install this package through command line or Manage NuGet Package, it could installed successful. Please provide the detailed steps about how do you operated to help us reproduce this issue.